# New posts are not showing up on my front page

Tags: plugins, posts

few weeks ago I installed revive old posts plugin on my site after some Weeks
The plugin ain't working the way I wanted then I had to deactivate and delete the plugin but right now am facing a problem of my new posts not showing up On my site first page what is showing are old  posts that where revived by the plugin before I deleted it please someone should take a look at my site and tell me what to do please     [litemusics.com](https://litemusics.com)

Comment: So I'm not familiar with that plugin, but have you checked the published date on the old posts that are appearing on the home page? Maybe the plugin changed the published date on the old posts to newer dates, which is causing them to float to the top of the list of posts.

Comment: Hello @Felicia - welcome to the WordPress Development community! This is a question which you'll probably need to pose in the official support channels for the plugin.